# mousedown / mouseup events on ExtJS 4 buttons

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, mouseevent, dom-events

I'm trying to make a button fire the mousedown and mouseup events on ExtJS 4, but I cannot find a properly way to do this.

I was trying to do something like this on my controller:

```
init: function()
{
    this.control(
    {
       'button[itemId="pttButton"]': 
       {
          mousedown: doSomething,
          mouseUp:   doSomethingElse
       }
    });
}
```

but these events don't seem to exist.

What's the best way to do this other than access directly the dom and using native Javascript events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because button does not have `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, easiest way is to add listeners for this events on the button component's element. Element which representing component you can get by component's `getEl()` method.

```
    var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });

    btn.mon(btn.getEl(), {
        mousedown: function() {
            console.log('down');
        },
        mouseup: function() {
            console.log('up');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Button object doesn't have mousedown or mouseup events. If its all the same to you, you could use the **click** event.